# Slow over time on collision with a FrostBullet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, 2d-games, slowdown

I'm new at Unity and C#. I started this 2D game few weeks ago.

So basically what I want to do is when the player is hit by "FrostBullet", it should deal the damage and slow that player over time. In my script the player is hit by FrostBullet, it deals the damage and the slow is constant, not over time.
I want it to be like, when the player is hit by FrostBullet, the player should be slowed for 2 sec and than his movement speed is back to normal.

So this is how my code look like:

```
public class FrostHit : MonoBehaviour 
{
float maxS = 40f;
float slowSpeed = 20f;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
int damage = -5;
int timeOfReducedSpeed = 2;
bool isHit = false;


void Start()
{
    rb.velocity = transform.right * slowSpeed;
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player_Njinja")
    {
       HealthNjinja healthNjinja = other.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthNjinja>();
       healthNjinja.ModifyHealth(damage);

       PlayerMovementNjinja reduceMoveSpeed = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovementNjinja>();
       reduceMoveSpeed.runSpeed = slowSpeed;

       Destroy(gameObject);
    }

      PlayerMovementKnight maxSpeed = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovementKnight>();
      maxSpeed.runSpeed = maxS;
      HealthKnight healthKnight = other.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthKnight>();

     if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player_Knight")
      {
        isHit = true;
        healthKnight.ModifyHealth(damage);
        StartCoroutine(speedTime());

        Destroy(gameObject);
     }
     IEnumerator speedTime()
     {
        while (isHit == true)
        {
            slowPlayer();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeOfReducedSpeed);
            revertSpeed();
        }
      }
     void slowPlayer()
     {
        maxSpeed.runSpeed = slowSpeed;
     }
     void revertSpeed()
     {
        maxSpeed.runSpeed = maxS;
     }
}
```

}

Also my PlayerMovement code:

```
public class PlayerMovementKnight : MonoBehaviour
{
public CharacterController2D controller;
public Animator animator;

public float runSpeed = 40f;
float horizontalMove = 0f;
bool jump = false;
bool crouch = false;

public WeaponKnight Bullet;
public bool grounded;

void Update()
{
    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;
    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horizontalMove));

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        jump = true;
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
    {
       crouch = true;
    }

   else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
   {
       crouch = false;
   }
   if (grounded && GetComponent<Bullet>().knockBack == false)
   {
       GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
   }

}
public void OnLanding()
{
    animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
}
public void OnCrouching(bool isCrouching)
{
    animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", isCrouching);
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
    jump = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your `bool isHit`, that is set to `true` before calling the Coroutine, is never reset to `false`.

So the loop:

```
while (isHit == true)
    {
        slowPlayer();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeOfReducedSpeed);
        revertSpeed();
    }
```

is really an infinite loop.
You might want to reset the bool to false somewhere.

**Edit:**

Following to comments, I see now that your script is attached to the bullet GameObject. After starting the Coroutine, and slowing down the player, you `Destroy(gameObject);`
After that, the script gets destroyed too, and the Coroutine is therefore stopped...and nothing remains to restore player’s speed back to normal.

You should move the Coroutine to the player’s script, and start it when needed. This way, it would still exist after you destroy the bullet.

Comment: Thannk you! I shouldn't use the **bool isHit** at all.

Comment: I'm happy that I've been helpful. If my answer solved your issue, consider marking it as accepted answer!  :)

Comment: It solved one of my problems, but unfortunately not the whole issue.

Still FrostBullet does deal the damage and slow the player down, but the slow is all the time (constant). It should be over course of 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Corrected answer after comments

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just deleted Destroy(object) to see if it will restore player's speed back to normal and it did. Now I'll try to move my code to the player's script. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your bool `isHit` is never set to false. Resulting in the Player being slowed and then being reset forever after he get's hit once.

As well as creating `isHit` in the first place isn't needed. Why would you need to check that the Player has been hit when you enter the `IEnumerator` only when the `Player_Knight` has been hit anyway.

**Code Example:**

```
public class FrostHit : MonoBehaviour
{
    float maxS = 40f;
    float slowSpeed = 20f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    int damage = -5;
    int timeOfReducedSpeed = 2;

    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.right * slowSpeed;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player_Njinja")
        {
            HealthNjinja healthNjinja = other.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthNjinja>();
            healthNjinja.ModifyHealth(damage);

            PlayerMovementNjinja mSpeedNinja = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovementNjinja>();
            StartCoroutine(speedTimeNinja());
        }

        else if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player_Knight")
        {
             HealthKnight healthKnight = other.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthKnight>();
            healthKnight.ModifyHealth(damage);

            PlayerMovementKnight mSpeedKnight = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovementKnight>();
            StartCoroutine(speedTimeKnight());
        }
 
        // Destroy Bullet
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    
    IEnumerator speedTimeKnight()
    {
        mSpeedKnight.runSpeed = slowSpeed;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeOfReducedSpeed);
        mSpeedKnight.runSpeed = maxS;
    }

    IEnumerator speedTimeNinja()
    {
        mSpeedNinja.runSpeed = slowSpeed;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeOfReducedSpeed);
        mSpeedNinja.runSpeed = maxS;
    }
}
```

**Things I've changed and the reason:**

1. Removed bool as well as while loop, didn't solve any real purpose
2. Seperated IEnumerator and 2 Functions from inside `OnTriggerEnter2D()`
3. Added `Destroy(gameObject);` to the end, because the bullets always gets destroyed anyway
4. Removed  `maxSpeed.runSpeed = maxS;`, because the speed get's set/reset already anyway. There is no reason to reset the speed after we collided with the bullet.
5. Put `GetComponent` for `Player_Knight` into the else if, there is no reason to execute the `GetComponent` even if the `Player_Njinja` gets hit.
6. Removed `reduceMoveSpeed.runSpeed = slowSpeed;` the `Player_Njinja` only gets slowed and never regains his speed. Instead use the IEnumerator again
7. Added another IEnumerator so that both `Player_Njinja` and `Player_Knight` get slowed and unslowed correctly (it would now be even possible  to create different slow times depending on which player gets hit)
8. Removed functions, it's not really worth it to write a function for one line of code. Especially when you can just set it in IEnumerator without needing more lines of code

Comment: MathewHD, the core of your answer (isHit never reset to false) has been already pointed out 7 hours ago. For the rest, there’re a lot of assumptions on the game’s logic in your answer, while we don’t really know anything about it. IsHit might serve to govern what happens on subsequent hits during the two seconds (ignored?summed?time prolonged?). 3. Bullets should not be destroyed but pooled. For the rest, for example, we don’t know if there are more players so both ninja and knight might be in game at the same time, and you now slow down both...

Comment: Thank you for the answer @MathewHD. Your code looks more clean, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. Still it does deal the damage and slow the player down, but the slow is all the time (constant). It should be over course of 2-3 seconds.
It doesnt allow me to use ref (Reference): "Iterators cannot have ref, in or out parametars"

I also added my PlayerMovement code in the question.
For me it looks like it should work now. I don't know what is the problem.

I recorded the game and this is how it looks like (at 0:47 sec): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91lW6Xh7Cuw

Comment: I watched the video and edited my code, if the passing by reference doesn't work. I don't know another way but to use 2 IEnumerators. 1 for each Player hope this helps.

Comment: Still doesnt work. I know what is causing the problem, but I don't know why.
Somehow the IEnumerator is not working properly.
I put the debug.log to test what happens. And after `yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeOfReducedSpeed);` nothing happens. Output is only "Slow Speed", but it should also "Max Speed" after 2 seconds, right?

`IEnumerator speedTimeKnight()
  {
        mSpeedKnight.runSpeed = slowSpeed;
        Debug.Log("Slow Speed");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeOfReducedSpeed);
        mSpeedKnight.runSpeed = maxSpeed;
        Debug.Log("Max Speed");
  }`

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: What was the problem and could you add the answer yourself or mark the correct answer?